# Python3.5.2 error - QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices

Tags: python3, pyqt5

[image]
I have tried so many times but it is showing the same error as in the above image:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

I have this error please help me to solve

Comment: You do not use the python packages of Ubuntu. Why? How do you have installed your Python? Pip or anaconda or...? Do you installed PyQt5 (or similar) on purpose?

Comment: i am using default python package which is comes with ubuntu. and i had used the following code to download PyQt5 for the creating small GUI Application. pip3 install pyqt5 .after successfully installed i tried this pip3 freeze the PyQt5 modules are present in the dist-packages

Answer (score 1):

Try to install PyQt5 with version < 5.11 using pip

```
sudo pip3 install -U "PyQt5<5.11"
```

if you don't have pip you can install it first from ubuntu's apt using

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

or from pypa.io using

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```